# How to use 9-patch image in Wpf-app

Tags: c#, android, wpf, nine-patch

I need to create and use [9-patch image](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) ( *.9.png, like in android) in WPF-app!
Only one question - HOW?

Comment: How what? To create or to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WPF doesn't support 9-patch format out of the box that I'm aware of, so you're looking at a custom control - that said, I imagine it'd be one of the more "reasonable" controls to put together: really you'd be looking at setting up...well, to be simple, 9 different Images, each set Stretch to extents, all wrapped within a...oh, let's pick a DockPanel for the hell of it. The control template might look something like:

(warning: slightly inebriated and free-handling this on a bloody phone, so likely not compile-able...in fact, now that I think of it, a Grid would probably be a wiser choice (3x3 rows cols, each cell with an image), but I shall persist in my original suggestion!)

```
<DockPanel>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding LeftTopImage}"/>
        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right" Source="{Binding RightTopImage}"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding CenterTopImage}"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Left">
        <Image Source="{Binding CenterLeftImage}"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <Image Source="{Binding CenterRightImage}"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Left" Source="{Binding LeftBottomImage}"/>
        <Image DockPanel.Dock="Right" Source="{Binding RightBottomImage}"/>
        <Image Source="{Binding CenterBottomImage}"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding CenterImage}"/>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a out-of-the-box content control use single image make 9-patch background.
Enjoy it!

```
//Code Auther: Mr. Squirrel.Downy (Flithor)
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Flithor_ReusableCodes
{
    public class NinePatchPanel : ContentControl
    {
        ImageSource[] patchs;

        [Category("Background")]
        [Description("Set nine patch background image")]
        public ImageSource BackgroundImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(BackgroundImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(BackgroundImageProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("BackgroundImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(NinePatchPanel), new PropertyMetadata(null, SetImg));

        [Category("Background")]
        [Description("Set the center split area")]
        public Int32Rect CenterArea
        {
            get { return (Int32Rect)GetValue(CenterAreaProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CenterAreaProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty CenterAreaProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CenterArea", typeof(Int32Rect), typeof(NinePatchPanel), new PropertyMetadata(Int32Rect.Empty, SetArea));

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            if (patchs != null)
            {
                double x1 = patchs[0].Width, x2 = Math.Max(ActualWidth - patchs[2].Width, 0);
                double y1 = patchs[0].Height, y2 = Math.Max(ActualHeight - patchs[6].Height, 0);
                double w1 = patchs[0].Width, w2 = Math.Max(x2 - x1, 0), w3 = patchs[2].Width;
                double h1 = patchs[0].Height, h2 = Math.Max(y2 - y1, 0), h3 = patchs[6].Height;
                var rects = new[]
                {
                new Rect(0, 0, w1, h1),
                new Rect(x1, 0, w2, h1),
                new Rect(x2, 0, w3, h1),
                new Rect(0, y1, w1, h2),
                new Rect(x1, y1, w2, h2),
                new Rect(x2, y1, w3, h2),
                new Rect(0, y2, w1, h3),
                new Rect(x1, y2, w2, h3),
                new Rect(x2, y2, w3, h3)
            };
                for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
                {
                    dc.DrawImage(patchs[i], rects[i]);
                }
            }
            base.OnRender(dc);
        }

        private static void SetArea(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var np = d as NinePatchPanel;
            if (np == null) return;
            var bm = np.BackgroundImage as BitmapSource;
            if (bm != null) SetPatchs(np, bm);
        }
        private static void SetImg(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var np = d as NinePatchPanel;
            if (np == null) return;
            var bm = np.BackgroundImage as BitmapSource;
            if (np.CenterArea == Int32Rect.Empty)
            {
                var w1_3 = bm.PixelWidth / 3;
                var h1_3 = bm.PixelHeight / 3;
                np.CenterArea = new Int32Rect(w1_3, h1_3, w1_3, h1_3);
            }
            else
            {
                SetPatchs(np, bm);
            }
        }

        private static void SetPatchs(NinePatchPanel np, BitmapSource bm)
        {
            int x1 = np.CenterArea.X, x2 = np.CenterArea.X + np.CenterArea.Width;
            int y1 = np.CenterArea.Y, y2 = np.CenterArea.Y + np.CenterArea.Height;
            int w1 = np.CenterArea.X, w2 = np.CenterArea.Width, w3 = bm.PixelWidth - np.CenterArea.X - np.CenterArea.Width;
            int h1 = np.CenterArea.Y, h2 = np.CenterArea.Height, h3 = bm.PixelHeight - np.CenterArea.Y - np.CenterArea.Height;
            np.patchs = new[] {
            new CroppedBitmap(bm, new Int32Rect(0, 0, w1, h1)),
            new CroppedBitmap(bm, new Int32Rect(x1, 0, w2, h1)),
            new CroppedBitmap(bm, new Int32Rect(x2, 0, w3, h1)),
            new CroppedBitmap(bm, new Int32Rect(0, y1, w1, h2)),
            new CroppedBitmap(bm, new Int32Rect(x1, y1, w2, h2)),
            new CroppedBitmap(bm, new Int32Rect(x2, y1, w3, h2)),
            new CroppedBitmap(bm, new Int32Rect(0, y2, w1, h3)),
            new CroppedBitmap(bm, new Int32Rect(x1, y2, w2, h3)),
            new CroppedBitmap(bm, new Int32Rect(x2, y2, w3, h3))
        };
        }
    }
}
```

---

#### Preview

BackgroundImage:
[image]
CenterArea: 10,10,10,10

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar request, and ending up here and other web places (in particular [here](https://wldevries.wordpress.com/2014/06/08/image-ninegrid-for-wpf/) as my answer is very influenced by his [code](https://gist.github.com/wldevries/14c6b07edf40459579cf))

I created a new UserControl (on Visual Studio, right click on project and chose [Add new Element ...] -> WPF -> UserControl)

*(note : replace {YOUR_PROJECT_NAMESPACE} with your personal project namespace)*

Here is the XAML code of my new UserControl :

```
<UserControl x:Class="{YOUR_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}.NineSliceImage"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Simple_DNS_Changer"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">

<Grid>        
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ColRowSize.Left}"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ColRowSize.Right}"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ColRowSize.Top}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ColRowSize.Bottom}"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--
    ­­▓░░
    ░░░
    ░░░
    -->
    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImgSource}" Viewbox="{Binding ViewBoxes[0]}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!--
    ­­░▓░
    ░░░
    ░░░        
    -->
    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="1"><!--HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"-->
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImgSource}" Viewbox="{Binding ViewBoxes[1]}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!--
    ­­░░▓
    ░░░
    ░░░        
    -->
    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Column="2">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImgSource}" Viewbox="{Binding ViewBoxes[2]}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!--
    ­­░░░
    ▓░░
    ░░░
    -->
    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="1"><!--VerticalAlignment="Stretch"-->
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImgSource}" Viewbox="{Binding ViewBoxes[3]}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!--
    ­­░░░
    ░▓░
    ░░░
    -->
    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"><!--HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"-->
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImgSource}" Viewbox="{Binding ViewBoxes[4]}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!--
    ­­░░░
    ░░▓
    ░░░
    -->
    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"><!--VerticalAlignment="Stretch"-->
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImgSource}" Viewbox="{Binding ViewBoxes[5]}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!--
    ­­░░░
    ░░░
    ▓░░
    -->
    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="2">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImgSource}" Viewbox="{Binding ViewBoxes[6]}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!--
    ­­░░░
    ░░░
    ░▓░
    -->
    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"><!--HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"-->
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImgSource}" Viewbox="{Binding ViewBoxes[7]}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <!--
    ­­░░░
    ░░░
    ░░▓
    -->
    <Rectangle SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding ImgSource}" Viewbox="{Binding ViewBoxes[8]}"/>
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
</Grid></UserControl>
```

Then the Code behind :

```
namespace {YOUR_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}
{
/// <summary>
/// Logique d'interaction pour NineSliceImage.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class NineSliceImage : UserControl
{
    [Description("The source of the image to be '9 sliced'")]
    public ImageSource ImgSource
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImgSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImgSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Source.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImgSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ImgSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(NineSliceImage), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    [Description("Where to cut the image to get the resulting 9 slices (Defined as pixel from 'Left,Top,Right,Bottom' edge of the image)")]
    public Thickness Slice
    {
        get { return (Thickness)GetValue(SliceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SliceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Slice.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SliceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Slice", typeof(Thickness), typeof(NineSliceImage), new PropertyMetadata(new Thickness()));

    [Description("Define the size of each new sliced area to be displayed as 'Left,Top,Right,Bottom' for {Left} width, {Right} width, {Top} height and {Bottom} height.\n By default this property is equal to Slice if not defined")]
    public Thickness AreasSize
    {
        get { return (Thickness)GetValue(AreasSizeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AreasSizeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for GridSize.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AreasSizeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AreasSize", typeof(Thickness), typeof(NineSliceImage), new PropertyMetadata(new Thickness()));
            
    private Rect[] _viewBoxes;

    public Rect[] ViewBoxes {
        get
        {
            if (_viewBoxes == null || _viewBoxes.Length < 9 || _viewBoxes.Any(x => x==null))
                _viewBoxes = GetViewBoxes();
            return _viewBoxes;
        }
        set => _viewBoxes = value; }

    private Thickness _colRowSize;

    public Thickness ColRowSize {
        get
        {
            if (_colRowSize == null || _colRowSize == new Thickness())
            {
                double left = AreasSize.Left, right = AreasSize.Right, top = AreasSize.Top, bottom = AreasSize.Bottom;
                double parentWidth = 1, parentHeight = 1;
                var parent = HelperUtils.FindClosestParent<FrameworkElement>(this, x => x is FrameworkElement);

                // if left / right size are relative (proportional)
                if (AreasSize.Left + AreasSize.Right <= 1 && parent != null)                        
                    parentWidth = parent.ActualWidth;

                // if top / bottom size are relative (proportional)
                if (AreasSize.Top + AreasSize.Bottom <= 1 && parent != null)
                    parentHeight = parent.ActualHeight;                    
                
                _colRowSize = new Thickness(left*parentWidth, top*parentHeight, right*parentWidth, bottom*parentHeight);
            }
            return _colRowSize;
        }
        set => _colRowSize = value; }

    private Rect[] GetViewBoxes()
    {
        var res = new Rect[9];
        var slice = Slice;
        double left = Slice.Left, right = Slice.Right, top = Slice.Top, bottom = Slice.Bottom;

        if (slice.Left + slice.Right > 1)
        {
            left = slice.Left / this.ImgSource.Width;
            if (left > 1) left = 1;
            right = slice.Right / this.ImgSource.Width;
            if (right > 1) right = 1;
        }

        if (slice.Top + slice.Bottom > 1)
        {
            top = slice.Top / this.ImgSource.Height;
            if (top > 1) top = 1;
            bottom = slice.Bottom / this.ImgSource.Height;
            if (bottom > 1) bottom = 1;
        }


        double horizontalMid = 1 - left - right;
        if (horizontalMid < 0) horizontalMid = 0;
        double verticalMid = 1 - bottom - top;
        if (verticalMid < 0) verticalMid = 0;

        res[0] = new Rect(0, 0, left, top);
        res[1] = new Rect(left, 0, horizontalMid, top);
        res[2] = new Rect(1 - right, 0, right, top);

        res[3] = new Rect(0, top, left, verticalMid);
        res[4] = new Rect(left, top, horizontalMid, verticalMid);
        res[5] = new Rect(1 - right, top, right, verticalMid);

        res[6] = new Rect(0, 1 - bottom, left, bottom);
        res[7] = new Rect(left, 1 - bottom, horizontalMid, bottom);
        res[8] = new Rect(1 - right, 1 - bottom, right, bottom);

        return res;
    }   

    public NineSliceImage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

}

And In your MainWindow code behind :

```
public {YOUR_PROJECT_WINDOW}()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        //Find all custom UserControl NineSliceImage, and set their AreasSize if needed
        var defaultThickness = new Thickness();
        foreach (var nineSliceImg in HelperUtils.FindAllChildren<NineSliceImage>(this, x => x is NineSliceImage))
        {
            if (nineSliceImg.AreasSize == defaultThickness)
                nineSliceImg.AreasSize = nineSliceImg.Slice;
        }
        [...]
    }
```

And for using it in your main Window XAML :

```
<local:NineSliceImage x:Name="Save9SliceImg" ImgSource="/Assets/SaveBIG.png" Slice="225,225,225,300" AreasSize="25,25,25,0"/>
```

You may need to Clean solution and regenerate solution.

As you see I ended up with a kinda ugly workaround to make the AreasSize Dependency Property having by default its corresponding Slice Dependency Property ... If you know a better way ?

Answer (score -5):

You can create 9patch images with the draw9patch tool from Android SDK. 
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: Ok, I know it. Is wpf support this type of image?

Comment: @user1616443, If you know it, why do you ask a question on how to create a 9-patch?

Comment: Egor, I know how create and use in Android, but i thing wpf does support 9.png format. (May be support, but work incorrect). And I need another solution of my problem. May be it's another format of image and another editor for creating it.